# Locally Weighted Linear Regression implementation in either R or Python

Tags: r, regression, machine-learning, python

i know statsmodel library in Python and in R, lowess and loess functions are available for this but i have a few problems with them:

1- i can't seem to be able to make predictions on new data for either

2- it doesn't seem to support a feature space grater than 1

is there anyway to implement Locally Weighted Linear Regression without these problems? (preferably in Python)

UPDATE: according to [@xavier-bourret-sicotte's answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/358603/locally-weighted-linear-regression-implementation-in-either-r-or-python/358942#358942) i used Alexandre Gramfort's implementation for this but still it doesn't seem that i can predict on new unseen data (test set)? is there anyway to implement this in the context of sklearn so we can use predict method?

Comment: Why don't you fit a generalized additive model (GAM)?

Comment: thank you, GAM seems to be a very good alternative, but still its peculiar that for lowess algorithm which at least in theory seems like a very effective model there is not one complete and comprehensive implementation available for it.

Comment: Re your comment on sklearn - it is not implemented in sklearn and i remember seeing a discussion on github which said it wouldn't be added to future releases - your options are to implement yourself or use R for example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there anyway to implement Locally Weighted Linear Regression without these problems? (preferably in Python)

Yes, you can use Alexandre Gramfort's implementation - available on his [Github page](https://gist.github.com/agramfort/850437). (Alexandre is a core developer of Sklearn)

You can also have a look a [this blog post](https://xavierbourretsicotte.github.io/loess.html) which shows the implementation on a toy example as well as the maths behind the vectorized implementation

[image]

Comment: thank you so much, really helpful links especially your blog post was gave great intuition and examples but when i tried to implement this i came across some problems. i updated my question i would really appreciate it if you can help with the problems.

Comment: @johnd sure no problem - however stats.stackexchange is not the right place to ask for code review or bug explanations and your question as it stands will most likely be closed - could please revert to your previous question ? If you need help with this particular error please post a question on stackoverflow or a code review website - Also if you are satisfied with my answer please feel free to accept it and upvote :)

Comment: Re your error I think it comes form the fact you are using pandas - Alexandre's implementation will require numpy arrays and won't work with pandas as it involves matrix multiplication and inversion...

Answer (score 0):

Not answering in detail how to implement it, however you can look at the code or just use this library: https://github.com/yaniv-shulman/rsklpr. Note it is quite similar to Lowess but not exactly the same since it uses robust weights in a single iteration instead of an iterative fit. You can also use it to calculate confidence intervals.

Disclosure, I'm the author of said library.